# getCachedFormulaResultType() of Apache POI returns incorrect type

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel sheet.  Initially (till rowid 30) I am getting the correct (CELL_TYPE_STRING) result type for the formula cell, but from row id 31 onwards I receive the incorrect (CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) result type.

Please see the logs below: I have used `====` as delimiter for separating logs for each row. Column number 1 is the point to focus, where for rowID=30 I get type=String whereas for rowId=31 I get type=Numeric, but column 1 for each row is of type string therefore I am missing how to get a string value.

Please see the Excel sheet content for the row corresponding to the log.

```
        switch (cell.getCellType()) {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            cellWrapper.setCellValueFarmula(true);
            switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                cellValue = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                logged.append("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                cellValue = "" + cell.getRichStringCellValue();
                logged.append("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_STRING");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                cellValue = "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                logged.append("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                cellValue = "error! ";
                logged.append("CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_ERROR");
                break;

            default:
                cellValue = null;
                logged.append("case not captured" + " type fetched = " + cell.getCellType());
                break;
            }
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            logged.append("CELL_TYPE_BLANK");
            cellValue = null;
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            cellValue = "error!";
            logged.append("CELL_TYPE_ERROR");
            break;
... some for cases below
```

Excel content

```
   Col1                                                    Col2                                   Col3                 Col4
[ACTIVE] - 21 - 1A - CALDRA - 305     .  {Chitra Subramaniam - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}    12               Rs. 1,000
[ACTIVE] - 22 - 1A - CALDRA - 306     .  {Parasad Parigi - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}        25               Rs. 1,000
[SEALED] - 23 - 1A - CALDRA - 401     .  {Vivek - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}                 <empty cell>     Rs. 1,075
```

log

```
==================================================================================================
Cell @ row=30col=1   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_STRING  Value=[ACTIVE] - 21 - 1A - CALDRA - 305     .
Cell @ row=30col=2   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_STRING  Value= {Chitra Subramaniam - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}
Cell @ row=30col=3   type = CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC    Value=12.0
Cell @ row=30col=4   type = CELL_TYPE_STRING     Value=Rs. 1,000
==================================================================================================
Cell @ row=31col=1   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC     Value=0.0
Cell @ row=31col=2   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_STRING  Value= {Parasad Parigi - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}
Cell @ row=31col=3   type = CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC    Value=25.0
Cell @ row=31col=4   type = CELL_TYPE_STRING     Value=Rs. 1,000
==================================================================================================
Cell @ row=32col=1   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC     Value=0.0
Cell @ row=32col=2   type = CELL_TYPE_FORMULA->CELL_TYPE_STRING  Value= {Vivek - 9538924280}, {deepakag@yahoo.com}
Cell @ row=32col=3   type = CELL_TYPE_BLANK  Value=null
Cell @ row=32col=4   type = CELL_TYPE_STRING     Value=Rs. 1,075
==================================================================================================
```

So how can I retrieve the cell result value, even if the value is numeric?
Is there a generic method that will give the result value in string form irrespective of what type of cell is?

Comment: Did you try DataFormatter? That's the normal way to turn a number + formatting rules into a string

Comment: @Gagravarr No i didn't try DataFormatter. How to use DataFormatter. Could you please explain it in little more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cells in Excel can have a number of different types. POI gives you back the cell value as Excel stored it, which may well not be how Excel displays it. (Excel can be a bit mysterious that way!).

If you want POI to try to format the cell to look like it does in Excel, no matter the type, then the class you're looking for is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). Your code would be something like:

```
 DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
 for (Row r : sheet) {
    for (Cell c : r) {
       CellReference cr = new CellRefence(c);
       System.out.println("Cell " + cr.formatAsString() + " is " + 
                          fmt.formatCellValue(c) );
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is there any provision in POI which let the developer to feed only String value in the cell and POI automatically converts it into appropriate format of the cell.

Comment: Although i fixed the issue by explicitly selecting the column in the excel sheet and set its type to text ( which was earlier pointing to numeric ), but i will give a try to this approach also.

Comment: If you have a String, give POI the string. If you have a number, give POI the number + optionally a formatting rule. That's exactly what Excel does for you

Comment: If i have a numeric value stored in String variable. e.g `String a = "12";`, then can POI convert it into numeric format internally, or i have to convert it into numeric format first and pass it to POI

Comment: You need to convert it youself, plus that way you get full control