# getCachedFormulaResultType() returns incorrect type 5 + Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have evaluated all formulas using **wrkBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();**
When I am trying to get cell type using getCachedFormulaResultType() returns incorrect type 5.

Note : I am trying to evaluate dependent cell formulas
E.g. Cell **E2** formula is **=TEXT(NOW(), "hh:mm:ss")** and Cell F2 formula is **=TEXT(TIME(HOUR(VALUE(E2)),MINUTE(VALUE(E2))+2,SECOND(VALUE(E2))+2),"hh:mm:ss")**

here is my getCellValue code :

```
public String getCellValue(int cellType, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell) 
{
    String value = "";

    if (cell != null) 
    {
        switch (cellType) 
        {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

        value=            
           handleStringCase(cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString());

             break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))
            {
                Date date2 = cell.getDateCellValue();
                String dateFmt = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
                value = new CellDateFormatter(dateFmt).format(date2);

                try {
                    if(value.startsWith("[$") && value.endsWith(";@"))
                    {
                        value = value.split("]")[1];
                        value = value.split(";")[0];
                    }
                    else if(value.startsWith("[$") && !value.endsWith(";@"))
                    {
                        value = value.split("]")[1];
                    }
                    else if(!value.startsWith("[$") && value.endsWith(";@"))
                    {
                        value = value.split(";")[0];
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    logger.error("Exception :", e);
                }

            }else
            {
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            }

            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

            cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            value = cell.getStringCellValue();
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:

            value = "";
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:

        value = getCellValue(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(), cell);
            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            System.out.println("ERROR : "+ cellType);
            break;
        default:

            return value;
        }
    } else 
    {
        return value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I understand that you have two cells (E2, F2) with formulas in them, and that you use your getCellValue method on them. But I don't understand what the expected behaviour is. Could you explain that...

Comment: When I am trying to evaluate dependent formulas, I get old values from excel.

Comment: OK; I have no idea, but maybe this link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489371/getcachedformularesulttype-of-apache-poi-returns-incorrect-type