# Can i extract the string NULL from a numeric cell with formula instead of 0 in .xlsx file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel column which contains the formula for all cells. When I am extracting the data the column is treated as Numeric. But for some cells, the result of the formula is "NULL". But when I am extracting data, it is coming as 0. If I am trying to use the evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell() , evaluator.evaluateInCell() then it is taking a long time. If I am trying to get the string from that cell then I am getting formula instead of value.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Below is my code.

```
        DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
        File destinationFile = new File(excelFileName);
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(destinationFile);) {
            List<Object> columnData = new ArrayList<>();
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet mySheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();
            rowIterator.next();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Cell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
                if (cell.getCellType() == CellType.FORMULA) {
                    switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                        case BOOLEAN:
                            columnData.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            columnData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            columnData.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case BLANK:
                            columnData.add("");
                            break;
                        case ERROR:
                            columnData.add("Error");
                            break;
                    }
                } else
                    columnData.add(df.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
            return columnData;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.getMessage();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            npe.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: The column which i am trying to extract is as below.                                             
 NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
0.003
NULL

Comment: Just for clarification ... are you looking to get the value of the cell, or its formula? It might help if you could tell us what library you are using that is defining the class Cell, as there are many ways to work with Excel.. In Excel, a cell is a Range object that can have a value, and a formula associated with it. I have to admit I am not familiar with the Java switch statement , but in C++ you can have a "default" which catches anything not matching one of the cases. Perhaps put that in, and see what you have.

Comment: Also, since this looks like an automation wrapper for Excel, in which case the type may come back as any of the VARIANT types, which include VT_EMPTY, VT_NULL, VT_ERROR and the somewhat unhelpful VT_UNKNOWN. VT_NULL. Your code doesn't seem to be testing all these possibilities.

Comment: I am using org.apache.poi for the above .xlsx file. I am trying to get only the values not the formulas. The result of the formula in  cell is NULL. Formula in the cell is like =IF(G2=0,"NULL",ROUND(G2,3))

Comment: All my cells are Numeric with formula and the execution is always going to the " case NUMERIC: columnData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue()); break; "

Comment: Your function in Excel is returning a string "NULL" explicitly. Just for a test, change your formula to =IF(G2=0,"FOO",ROUND(G2,3)) and see what happens. My suspicion is that somewhere in the POI, the string "NULL" is being coerced to be the number 0. This issue is also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489371/getcachedformularesulttype-of-apache-poi-returns-incorrect-type

Comment: Now for the same above code, I am getting NULL values also. I have just recalculated the formulas and saved the excel.  It seems like an excel glitch. Thank you @DS_London